# What App Engine datastore caching strategy will give complete cache consistency?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-datastore

App Engine NDB has a nice datastore caching strategy where it caches entities in memcache and goes to some lengths to make sure the cache is always in sync with the underlying datastore.

Here's a rundown of its strategy in pseudo code:

**Get entity from datastore:**

```
if entity in memcache:
    return entity
else:
    add memcache lock for entity
    get memcache lock for later CAS use
    check get memcache lock retrieved the same add memcache lock
    get entity from datastore
    save entity to memcache using CAS
    return entity
```

**Put entity into datastore:**

```
add memcache lock for entity
put entity into datastore
remove memcache lock
```

**Delete entity from datastore:**

```
add memcache lock for entity
delete entity from datastore
```

The beauty of this design is there are very few opportunities for the cache to go out of sync with the datastore. However, there are a couple of situations I can think of where it could happen:

1. If the memcache lock fails when deleting an entity.
2. If the memcache lock fails when updating an entity within a transaction.

I have described them in more detail here: https://github.com/qedus/nds/labels/consistency

What's a caching strategy that will not have any possible chance of the datastore becoming out of sync with the cache?

Comment: Are you asking me to design a perfect cache algorithm for nds? In a stack overflow answer?

Comment: Memcache is not guaranteed durable. It can flush at any time, for any reason. Thus, all code depending on memcache should be ready for this possiblity. If the memcache lock fails, and is expected to still exist later, this needs to be checked, and action needs to be taken if it's been disrupted.

Comment: Memcache eviction and random errors are two reasons why creating a system that guarantees completely consistent cache is difficult. Yes, I am asking you to design a perfect cache algorithm for App Engine that anyone can use, not just the nds package.